# Confusion over time.sleep in Python "while True" loop

Tags: python, signals

Level beginner
I am using python 2.7 version on ubuntu.
I have a confusion regarding a small code snippet in python. I know that `while True` in python means to loop infinitely. I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
import time

def ctrlc_catcher(signum, frm):
     print "Process can't be killed with ctrl-c!"

def alarm_catcher(signum,frame):
    print "Got an alarm"


signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrlc_catcher)
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_catcher)


while True:
   signal.alarm(1)
   pass
```

When I execute the programm the output is blank, when I hit Ctrl-C key it displays "Process can't be....." message.
My question is why the `signal.alarm(1)` is not working ?
However if I put a small pause using

```
while True:
   signal.alarm(1)
   time.sleep(1)
   pass
```

after it then the alarm gets triggered and in the output screen I see "Got an alarm" message after every second.
What is time.sleep(1) doing so that the alarm gets triggered? 
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first example you're constantly resetting the alarm. You set an alarm for 1 second from now, then 0.00001 seconds later you set an alarm for 1 second from now, then 0.00001 seconds later you set an alarm for 1 second from now... so the alarm is always 1 second in the future! In the second example, by sleeping, you allow 1 second to pass before you reset the alarm, so it actually has time to go off.

I think what you meant to write in your first example was

```
signal.alarm(1)
while True:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried this code before.My idea was to generate alarm every 1 second indefinitely, the code you mentioned will only generate alarm for once.

Comment: +1 @hobbs is correct that setting the alarm will cancel the previous alarm, thus ending up with infinite set/cancel of alarms.

Comment: @pss Then you have to re-schedule the alarm in the alarm handler (not sure if that's allowed) or to set a flag to be evaluated in the main loop.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are over writing your alarms. The following is from the [`signal` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.alarm):

> `signal.alarm(time)`
>
> If `time` is non-zero, this function requests that a
> `SIGALRM` signal be sent to the process in `time` seconds. **Any previously
> scheduled alarm is canceled** (only one alarm can be scheduled at any
> time).

Comment: +1 for posting the man page of signal.alarm. This will clearly unconfuse (if that's a word) anyone.